# Class 'JInput' not found after updating to 3.7.3

Tags: joomla-3.x, jinput

I am updating a clients site to 3.7.3 and following the update receive the following on both the front end and admin:

> Fatal error: Class 'JInput' not found in /home/wwwsitew/public_html/rmi/libraries/joomla/application/web.php on line 149

This refers to `{
            $this->input = new JInput;
        }`

In the following function:

```
public function __construct(JInput $input = null, Registry $config = null, JApplicationWebClient $client = null)
    {
        // If an input object is given use it.
        if ($input instanceof JInput)
        {
            $this->input = $input;
        }
        // Create the input based on the application logic.
        else
        {
            $this->input = new JInput;
        }

        // If a config object is given use it.
        if ($config instanceof Registry)
        {
            $this->config = $config;
        }
        // Instantiate a new configuration object.
        else
        {
            $this->config = new Registry;
        }

        // If a client object is given use it.
        if ($client instanceof JApplicationWebClient)
        {
            $this->client = $client;
        }
        // Instantiate a new web client object.
        else
        {
            $this->client = new JApplicationWebClient;
        }

        // Load the configuration object.
        $this->loadConfiguration($this->fetchConfigurationData());

        // Set the execution datetime and timestamp;
        $this->set('execution.datetime', gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $this->set('execution.timestamp', time());

        // Setup the response object.
        $this->response = new stdClass;
        $this->response->cachable = false;
        $this->response->headers = array();
        $this->response->body = array();

        // Set the system URIs.
    }
```

I cant seem to find anything related in Google, does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem could be?

---

Update: I have downloaded a full copy of 3.7.3 and uploaded both /libraries/joomla/application/web.php and libraries/joomla/input/input.php but I;m now getting a 404 error for both Front end and Admin pages....

---

Update2: It seems the DB is running at 3.7.0, the following issues show when trying to 'fix' the DB, however they are not fixed after clicking the button:

> Table 'uh46v_session' does not have column 'client_id' with type
>   tinyint(3). (From file 3.7.0-2016-10-02.sql.) Table
>   'uh46v_ucm_content' does not have column 'core_content_item_id' with
>   type int(10). (From file 3.7.0-2017-01-08.sql.) Table
>   'uh46v_ucm_content' does not have column 'asset_id' with type int(10).
>   (From file 3.7.0-2017-01-08.sql.) Table 'uh46v_ucm_content' does not
>   have column 'core_type_id' with type int(10). (From file
>   3.7.0-2017-01-08.sql.) Table 'uh46v_languages' does not have column 'asset_id' with type int(10). (From file 3.7.0-2017-03-03.sql.) Table
>   'uh46v_menu_types' does not have column 'asset_id' with type int(10).
>   (From file 3.7.0-2017-03-03.sql.)

I have tried manual updates of earlier Joomla versions, i.e 3.6, 3.7 and also reinstalling 3.5.1 which is the current version - I'm guessing the site owner may have corrupted something when trying to update or roll back?

---

Update 3: I have ran the Joomla FPA and the full details can be found [here](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=952644)

Update 4: Still no luck, all none core EXT's removed apart from Akeeba. There are some additional details [here](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=952644&p=3483624#p3483624)

I'm still investigating, but any suggestions welcome.

---

Regards
D

Comment: What happens if you add `use Joomla\Input\Input;` to line 14 of this file?

Comment: I've tried heavily to replicate this error but cannot seem to do so, so my above comment probably won't solve anything. In the Joomla backend, go to `Components >> Joomla Update` and try reinstalling the core.

Comment: Thanks @Lodder, I have installed via the Joomla update multiple times, but all to no affect. I have also added a php.ini in both the main directory and admin to specify the upload_tmp_directory but this does not seem to make a difference either.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Joomla! instance is corrupted. Since using the Joomla admin does not help with the re-installation, I would suggest Do a complete Joomla! Core manual re-installation / package replacement.

Note: This probably will work better in a local clone of the website on your desktop. Generally avoid doing this on the live website directly.

## Create a fresh the Joomla! Core on an existing website:

- Download your Joomla! version (3.7.3) full stable package from joomla.org
- Unzip it
- Start replacing everything Joomla! core in your instance.
- Open side by side the 2 folders where your site-clone and the unzipped fresh Joomla package reside.

### Administrator Site

Navigate in each of the admin site subfolders:

**a. Components, Modules, Includes folders.**

- Select all and copy the *subfolders/subcontent from fresh Joomla! of the above folders, and paste to your site. Let it replace any existing items.

  <sub>*subfolders = each core component, module folder and files -see screenshot</sub>

  [image: Selecting all admin components]

**b. Help, Manifests, Languages Folder**

- Likely you won't need to replace anything for these folders- but in case you do, select the content of their subfolders, copy and paste to your site's instance. (e.g. for languages, copy the contents of the core en-EN language folder and paste them to your site - replace existing ones).

**c. Templates**

- Unless you have any template overrides you can copy/paste the whole templates folder. If you have overrides, then save your overrides somewhere before replacing the templates and place them again to their previous location on the fresh templates.

---

### Front-end Site

Navigate in each of the site subfolders:

**a. bin, cli**

- Select all and copy the files of these folders from fresh Joomla! of the above folders, and paste to your site's instance. Let it replace any existing items.

**b. Includes, Layouts**

- Copy the whole folders and replace on your site's instance.

**c. Components, Libraries, Media, Modules**

- Copy the subfolders/contents of these folders (the ones of each module, component etc - as described for the administrator components) and replace on your site's instance.

**d. Languages and Templates**

- Navigate in each plugin's folder and copy the subfolders that exist there. Replace the items with the same name on your joomla site instance.

**e. Plugins**

- Similar as described for the admin site. Just note that if you are using 3rd party templates - then you need to copy from the fresh core only each subfolder that exist in the templates folder and not the whole folder.

---

### Conclusion - things to keep in mind:

- The above describe briefly how to completely replace the core Joomla files on an existing Joomla site - without removing 3rd party files.
- With this general approach, it's made sure that the whole Joomla core is there.
- Of course it's recommended that the Joomla versions should match.
- Other specific customizations/overrides/patches over the core of the existing site will be removed.
- If there are no 3rd party extensions and other files exist on the whole website or partially in subfolders e.g. a plugins folder, then the whole parent folder can be replaced.
- Always have a backup - avoid doing such tasks on the live website.
- Remember to clearing caches etc, when testing your changes.
- I am describing/suggesting the full core re-installation with this method because likely if there is a failed Joomla installation for whatever reason, this might contain more than 1 corrupted files. However, someone could go with partial replacements of the whole Joomla package and try on each step to see if a specific issue is resolved.

**Extra Tip**

I have found that in some cases, during copy/paste/replace from fresh Joomla to the site, it's useful and timesaver to temporary rename and keep aside some of the existing site folders - instead of replacing them (which deletes them) - so to keep references to them in my current working environment - without the need to look to re-download/re-unzip/recreate the existing site. I can easily rename folders and switch between the 2 versions - or do comparisons etc.

Comment: Thank you, I have already tried the file/replace method to no avail using various Joomla versions from 3.5.1 upwards, to no avail. I've also ran the DB queries manually from the administrator/com_admin/ folder following each file/replace - all again without success. It seems to lean more towards a DB issue. The 'PHP temporary directory not set' message still displays, however this is not an issue on any other site....its all very odd!!!

Comment: Just as an update, the 'PHP temporary directory not set' is still displayed even after a stock Softlaculous install - I;m not convinced its related.