# How to make manual re-installation of Joomla! Core without losing extensions?

Tags: update, installation, fatal-error, troubleshooting

Website is broken after update, Joomla core is corrupted, php fatal errors are thrown, backend is not accessible or backend re-installation isn't working and there is no backup of the site. How can I manually re-install Joomla core on an existing website?

<sub>This is a response question/answer for all type of questions where the above problems appear, to document the situation where a manual re-installation is needed and can act as reference for the future. The answer posted below is the same I posted recently on another question: [Class 'JInput' not found after updating to 3.7.3](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/21140/class-jinput-not-found-after-updating-to-3-7-3/)</sub>

<sub>Anyone can add more important points on other answers or improve the one posted below.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your Joomla! instance is corrupted. Since using the Joomla admin does not help with the re-installation, I would suggest Do a complete Joomla! Core manual re-installation / package replacement.

Note: This probably will work better in a local clone of the website on your desktop. Generally avoid doing this on the live website directly.

## Create a fresh the Joomla! Core on an existing website:

- Download your Joomla! version (3.7.3) full stable package from joomla.org
- Unzip it
- Start replacing everything Joomla! core in your instance.
- Open side by side the 2 folders where your site-clone and the unzipped fresh Joomla package reside.

### Administrator Site

Navigate in each of the admin site subfolders:

**a. Components, Modules, Includes folders.**

- Select all and copy the *subfolders/subcontent from fresh Joomla! of the above folders, and paste to your site. Let it replace any existing items.

  <sub>*subfolders = each core component, module folder and files -see screenshot</sub>

  [image: Selecting all admin components]

**b. Help, Manifests, Languages Folder**

- Likely you won't need to replace anything for these folders- but in case you do, select the content of their subfolders, copy and paste to your site's instance. (e.g. for languages, copy the contents of the core en-EN language folder and paste them to your site - replace existing ones).

**c. Templates**

- Unless you have any template overrides you can copy/paste the whole templates folder. If you have overrides, then save your overrides somewhere before replacing the templates and place them again to their previous location on the fresh templates.

---

### Front-end Site

Navigate in each of the site subfolders:

**a. bin, cli**

- Select all and copy the files of these folders from fresh Joomla! of the above folders, and paste to your site's instance. Let it replace any existing items.

**b. Includes, Layouts**

- Copy the whole folders and replace on your site's instance.

**c. Components, Libraries, Media, Modules**

- Copy the subfolders/contents of these folders (the ones of each module, component etc - as described for the administrator components) and replace on your site's instance.

**d. Languages and Templates**

- Navigate in each plugin's folder and copy the subfolders that exist there. Replace the items with the same name on your joomla site instance.

**e. Plugins**

- Similar as described for the admin site. Just note that if you are using 3rd party templates - then you need to copy from the fresh core only each subfolder that exist in the templates folder and not the whole folder.

---

### Conclusion - things to keep in mind:

- The above describe briefly how to completely replace the core Joomla files on an existing Joomla site - without removing 3rd party files.
- With this general approach, it's made sure that the whole Joomla core is there.
- Of course it's recommended that the Joomla versions should match.
- Other specific customizations/overrides/patches over the core of the existing site will be removed.
- If there are no 3rd party extensions and other files exist on the whole website or partially in subfolders e.g. a plugins folder, then the whole parent folder can be replaced.
- Always have a backup - avoid doing such tasks on the live website.
- Remember to clearing caches etc, when testing your changes.
- I am describing/suggesting the full core re-installation with this method because likely if there is a failed Joomla installation for whatever reason, this might contain more than 1 corrupted files. However, someone could go with partial replacements of the whole Joomla package and try on each step to see if a specific issue is resolved.

**Extra Tip**

I have found that in some cases, during copy/paste/replace from fresh Joomla to the site, it's useful and timesaver to temporary rename and keep aside some of the existing site folders - instead of replacing them (which deletes them) - so to keep references to them in my current working environment - without the need to look to re-download/re-unzip/recreate the existing site. I can easily rename folders and switch between the 2 versions - or do comparisons etc.