# Akeeba backup update broke the site

Tags: joomla-3.9, akeebabackup

I was trying to update Akeeba backup in my Joomla site.
After two seconds from start, my site returns with a 500 server error.
Definitely the "Akeeba update" was the culprit!

I think the reason was that my site was in the localhost and most probably somewhere Akeeba didn't find what it needed.

In my opinion, they have to support such cases for free (Their application update damaged my site, not anything else). But unfortunately for asking a question to them one should buy at least their ticket subscription for 50 Euros.

So my question.
How to restore the site to point before starting to update the Akeeba backup.

Comment: If an extension has broken your site, then remove that extension. Check also this: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/21209/how-to-make-manual-re-installation-of-joomla-core-without-losing-extensions

Comment: Have you tried this one https://www.akeebabackup.com/support/akeeba-backup-3x/Ticket/14539:500-internal-server-error-after-installing.html

Comment: Your question says that you were updating Akeeba, not installing it new, therefore is it right to assume that you have a back up of your site from before Akeeba allegedly caused problems. If so then you should restore the latest back up that you have for the site.

Comment: @webchun. I tried it, but didn't help.

Comment: This question is also asked at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62974705/1983389

Comment: If you feel there's a bug, you can contact the developer via email instead rather than paying for support.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good practice to always have up-to-date backups of your projects/sites. This way, you can always revert back to a previous working state.

If an extension has broken your site, then remove that extension.
You can do it manually by navigating to the directories of your Joomla site, where each extension places its files.

For example in the case of Akeeba, you can manually navigate to the `/administrator/components/` and rename or remove the `com_akeeba` folder, do the same for the `/components/com_akeeba` and all akeeba plugins in the plugins folder.

The following resources might be helpful:  [How to make manual re-installation of Joomla! Core without losing extensions?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/21209/how-to-make-manual-re-installation-of-joomla-core-without-losing-extensions)

https://www.akeebabackup.com/support/akeeba-backup-3x/Ticket/14539:500-internal-server-error-after-installing.html

---

#### Regarding Software Liability, Warranty and Support

After following the discussion in the comments (they are deleted now) and your demands for Free Support in your question: I feel we need to give a clear perspective regarding Open Source Software, the Liability and the responsibilities of the developers and the users.

Things to keep in mind:

- Software is a complex product. Many things can go wrong and there can be numerous factors that can affect its operation.
- At the same time, for your particular case, it's not certain that Akeeba software was responsible for your broken site.
- Nobody has forced you to use that piece of software.
- When using 3rd party software, you need to be aware about the terms of using it, its license and your rights. With the majority of the software out there, and especially the Open Source and/or free provided software, the end user accepts liability for the use of it and should be pre-cautious regarding any possible damage it may cause.
- Akeeba as many other similar software providers, develop open source software and provide it to the public. They offer a free version with limited features and a paid version with more features. When someone gets the paid version they opt in for the more features, pluss access to direct support from the developers.
  This is the way to support the developers in developing software that is useful for you, and also to get in touch with them for possible issues you might have by using it, which is actually a promise that they will try to help you as best as possible.
- It's more than clear that demanding free support for a free software makes no sense - and you knew it when you downloaded and installed the software that you won't be getting support for it - that was your choice, and you intentionally went for the free version.

---

> Akeeba Backup is under the [**GNU General Public License**](https://www.akeebabackup.com/license.html).
>
> Please read the Software Licence that you use.
>
> Pay attention at 15 and 16 points.  A brief summary of those 2
> paragraphs: the software is provided as is and the end user is
> responsible for its usage, and even a possible damage or loss of data
> caused by it.

Comment: This is important to say and you said it better than I attempted to.  That said, this does not attempt to resolve the question.  I deleted the comments between myself and the OP because they would not benefit researchers who encounter a similar issue themselves.  I will recommend that you transfer this valuable post to Meta, then leave a link under this question to direct users to your Meta post.

Comment: @mickmackusa - I added a bit of extra information regarding the actual issue, otherwise I feel it's gonna stay unanswered and think I am gonna leave the part regarding GNU etc here, as a response to the part of the question that demands free support. We can create a general Meta post for this - but have no time at the moment, to make it look and stand good there - Maybe if you could setup a proper question there, we could put the answer below. Let me know ... otherwise, one of the next days I will try to create a good meta post for this.

Comment: Thank you for first part of your advice. But,
1- Definitely it happened when updating the extension.
2- I can never understand why updating a component will damage the site to the server error extent and then the user has not an easy and reasonable way to contact and discuss the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a timely answer to my problem, so I used git stash to return to the last committed state of my site.